# Inserting Cell Values Into Specified Cell

Tags: excel, insert, vba

I am a complete beginner with Excel VBA. I am trying to produce a schedule tracker which has on the "Courses" worksheet all the teaching information of courses running.

Column E uses a formula to identify the cell which cross references the staff member and the course date.

Column K contains the concat (text & Numerical data) statement which I need to have inserted into the correct place on the "Calendar" worksheet (same workbook).

The Code I have so far is shown below:

```
Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click()

Dim w As Variant
Dim c As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
i = 1
w = Sheets("Courses").Range("E" & i).Value
c = Sheets("Courses").Range("K" & i).Value

Do
Sheets("Calendar").Range(w).Select
ActiveCell.Value = c.Value
Loop While n <> Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: Apologies for the vague question...Essentially how can I set up the loop so that it skims through the populated cells in column E, each holds a cell reference. It should then go to that specified cell reference on the Calendar sheet and populate it with the value from column K (same row) of the Courses sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Not too clear .. but you may try this ..

```
Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click()

Dim w As Variant
Dim c As Variant
Dim i, n As Integer
Dim r as Range

Set r = Range("E65536").End(xlup)

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 to r.Row
  w = Sheets("Courses").Range("E" & i).Value
  c = Sheets("Courses").Range("K" & i).Value

  Sheets("Calendar").Range(w).Select
  ActiveCell.Value = c.Value

  'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Next    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I have tried it and when I step into the code, I get as far as line 10 "Sheets("Calendar"... and I get an error message saying "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: Then either you dont have sheet named "Calendar" or the variable w does not contain a correct cell address.  Also you never really need to use select.  Change to `Sheets("Calendar").Range(w).Value = c.Value`